# Почему не отображается раздел в цепочке навигации?

Tags: битрикс

Почему страница может не отображаться в цепочке навигации? Файл `.section.php` присутствует, цепочка сама есть, а имени раздела в ней нет. Код в файле такой:

```
$sSectionName = "Раздел";
$arDirProperties = Array(

);
```

Если удалить `$sSectionName`, то цепочка навигации вообще исчезает.

Comment: Возможно ваш формат вывода цепочки навигации не показывает только последний элемент?

Answer (score 0):

Смотрите настройки компонента. Также прочтите - https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/?COURSE_ID=43&LESSON_ID=3398